# Can't connect to the internet

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, internet

My desktop of one year has never had a problem connecting to the Internet until about two days ago. When I  went to turn on my computer in the morning, nothing seemed different. When I went to start up my browser, it wouldn't load any pages. I thought it was weird since the other 4 computers in my house connected fine.

I tried everything I could think of: rebooting modem/router, resetting modem/router, restarting computer, using different browsers. Does anyone have any idea of what is going on?

I'm using Windows, and I can ping my router/modem.

Comment: What happens if you ping 4.2.2.2? how about a FQDN like www.google.com?

Comment: Can you ping the router?

Comment: Windows?  OSX?  Linux?

Comment: @Kyle I'm not sure, not home to test it right now.

Comment: @Matt Jenkins I can ping it the router and the modem.

Comment: @Wes Hardaker Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Some viruses like to set your proxy to be something very funky. You can change this in your web browser (Usually by going to the options menu, then going to the advance section). If you need to know how to do this more in-depth, I would Google "Change Proxy [Browser-name] (such as Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera)". This will test to see if that is what happened. To fix the problem if this is it, you must remove the virus. If you don't remove the virus, the proxy will keep on being reset, causing a lot of frustration.

Removing a virus the easy way is to reinstall your operating system (this will definitely remove it). Another way would be to use Trojan Remover, Malwarebytes, Spy-bot Search and Destroy, Ad-aware, and possibly more depending on what you prefer. I would use all of those. You should be good after that. (I even follow up by backing up my registry and using the Find function to find the virus keyword and removing the records.)

If you need anymore help, please let me know with a comment!

Comment: Yeah, I was starting the ponder the possibility of it being a virus, since I don't use any virus protection programs. I'll be sure to try it.

Comment: No proxy set up. No virus, I could have eliminated that because for a brief amount of time yesterday I was able to connect to the Internet.

Comment: Have you tried using multiple internet browsers? (i.e. download the Firefox installer from a computer that can access the internet, then install it on the other computer...) Another thought would be to check to make sure your default gateway isn't something funky... Please keep communicating with me, I want your problem to be fixed...

Comment: Yeah, I've went on Firefox, Chrome, IE9. Default gateway is my router.

Comment: I would start running virus scanners (one at a time...) as listed in my answer. Another possibility is that would be that you are have IP conflicts with your router. Check to make sure that the dhcp server (on your router) is set to give a large amount of IP addresses. Also, make sure that you computer is not using a static IP address, instead have it automatically get one from the DHCP server. Please respond with the outcome...

Comment: Nothing is wrong with my router, because there are about 8 other devices also connected to it and everyone else is working fine. I'm running a scan on NOD32 right now.

Comment: Well the thing I was worried about is an IP conflict which would allow others to be on fine, but this other machine is having issues because there are now more IP addresses. This would be like have eight sandwiches but having nine hungry people that will NOT share.

Comment: Well, the range is from 100-199 so theres no problem there.

Comment: nope... darn... I am running out of ideas... Hopefully the anti virus comes back ok... I know this could be a stretch, but did you check the hosts file? Some virus screw that up pretty bad...

Comment: Nothing in it. Scanner is at 88%

Comment: It finished. Nothing.

Comment: I would try more than one anti-virus, like I said in my answer... This is because different anti viruses check for different things or have different strengths.

Comment: I realize, but I really doubt it's a virus.
I'm reformating right now.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help... I hope reinstalling the OS fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS server address settings. If the failing machine was set to use DNS servers that are no longer reachable, but the other machines were using other DNS servers, that could explain your problems.

Try:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

Now try:

```
ping google-public-dns-a.google.com
```

Those are both the same host. If the numeric version worked and the hostname version didn't, then you have a DNS problem.